# curl git fails in when building docker image, but succeeds from local machine

Tags: windows, git, docker

I am using a curl command in a dockerfile to download the git installer.

```
curl -SL --output git-install.exe https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.41.0.windows.3/Git-2.41.0.3-64-bit.exe
```

When I build the dockerfile on my local computer, it fails with the error shown below. However, if I run the same command directly from cmd or PowerShell on my computer, it succeeds. We have successfully built the exact same dockerfile on two other machines, and they complete without any error. All three machines are running Windows Server 2022.

```
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
The command 'cmd /S /C curl -SL --output git-install.exe https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.41.0.windows.3/Git-2.41.0.3-64-bit.exe &&     start /w git-install.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh" &&     del /q git-install.exe' returned a non-zero code: 56
```

As a test, I removed the curl command from the dockerfile, and left three other curl commands that download different packages. That succeeded. So it seems that something is preventing only my computer from running that command, but only from within the docker build.

I have also tried downloading a newer version of Git instead, but with the exact same result.

How can I further troubleshoot this issue, and what can I try to fix this?

Comment: Which image are you using in your Dockerfile to run curl? Try running the command with verrbose enabled `curl -vvv -SL --output git-install.exe https://...`.

Comment: I'm using image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

Running with verbose enabled does produce more hints:

* schannel: server closed abruptly (missing close_notify)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with github.com port 443